# Ok so i've fixed it but i want to know how i can have all the value rows to show up if @custref is 9

Tags: sql, t-sql

> Write an SQL command that generates a stored procedure named
>   ‘spCustomerValue’ that  returns the total value of orders from the
>   OrderDetails table placed b y a customer whose  reference is passed in
>   as a parameter.

```
use SKILLAGEITDB
go

alter proc spCustomerValue 
(
@custref as  int
)
as 
begin
select sum(value) as "total Value"
```

from orderdetails
where custref = @custref

```
end 
go
```

exec  spCustomerValue  9

```
exec  spCustomerValue
```

Comment: perhaps try *create* instead of *alter*?

Comment: You will need to look at Itzik Ben-Gan's Books to learn TSQL,most of the things with your query is wrong  :http://tsql.solidq.com/

Comment: The only line after `as` should be `select sum(value) as "toast" from OrderDetails where custref = @custref`  Not the double select/assign thing you currently have.

Comment: Both answers below are correct, when executing the procedure, remember to pass in a custref value. Like this (or which ever custref you want) : `EXEC spCustomerValue 9`

Answer (score 0):

Both the `Select` queries inside the procedures are wrong

```
select  @custref = custref from orderdetails
```

The above query will re-assign the `@custref` variable with arbitrary `custref` from `orderdetails` table.

```
select sum(value) as "toast" 
from OrderDetails
where @custref = 9
```

In above query you have hard-coded the value `9` and check it with the `@custref` which is definitely wrong

You just need this

```
Alter proc spCustomerValue 
(
@custref as  int
)
as 
begin
    select sum(value) as "toast" 
    from OrderDetails
    where custref  = @custref 
End
```

**Update :** To show all values when `@custref = 9` then change the Where clause like this

```
select sum(value) as "toast" 
from OrderDetails
where custref  = @custref  OR @custref = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCustomerValue
(
@custref int
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(value) AS TotalOrderAmount
FROM OrderDetails
WHERE custref = @custref
END
```

To test this you must pass in a custref value

```
EXEC spCustomerValue 1
```

Comment: Long back I wrote similar answer ;)

Comment: Yeah I must not have refreshed the page, didn't see your answer. I commented on the question saying that both answers are correct, but reminded him to pass in the custref when executing the procedure